# window.open send parametrs

Tags: jquery, send, window.open

How I can send the result of a `window.open` page to a parent page?

I mean, do inverse this link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564980/javascript-form-select-element-open-url-in-new-window-and-submit-form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `window.opener` object, which is a reference to the global `window` object of the parent page.